# Why doesn't flex direction column with align-items=center center image properly

Tags: html, css, flexbox, less

I stumbled upon an issue with image centering within a flexbox with `direction:column`.

Imagine you have two elements within a flexbox, where the first one contains an image:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="image-container">
        <img class="img" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/firefox-logo.svg">
    </div>
    <div class="another-flex-child">
        Random content here
    </div>
</div>


.container {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  .image-container {
    flex: 1;
    align-self: center;

    .img {
      height: 100%;
    }
  }

  .another-flex-child {
    flex: none;
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

I would expect the image to be center horizontally within the div, but it appears the left border of the image is exactly at the center of the div.

When I replace the image with another div which contains some text it is placed as expected.

Can anybody explain to me whats happening there?

[Checkout this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v1cLhkuf/47/)

Comment: What do you need to retrieve? The two divs must be horizontally aligned? i mean image on the left and other div on the right?

Comment: I don't understand your comment...

Comment: i mean, do you want only to center the image and the text below horizontally?

Comment: No, I want to use the whole screen and the image should fill up all the remaining space while the other elements should take up only the space they require

Comment: That's not valid CSS. You must be using LESS or SCSS or some other processor. Would be nice to tag or otherwise let people know what that is.

Comment: @HereticMonkey true - will fix it

Comment: add justify-content: center; to .image-container and it should worrks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are using an SVG with no intrinsic dimension and only an intrinsic ratio so it's like your image has a width equal to 0 which make its centred container with a width equal to 0, too.

Here is before using `height:100%`

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.image-container {
  flex: 1;
  align-self: center;
  border:2px solid blue;
}

.img {
  /*height: 100%;*/
}

.another-flex-child {
  flex: none;
  background-color: red;
}

.spacer {
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img class="img" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/firefox-logo.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="another-flex-child">
    Random content here
  </div>
</div>

<div class="spacer"></div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <div>Properly centered content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="another-flex-child">
    Random content here
  </div>
</div>
```

After setting `height:100%` the image will fill all the space and will keep its ratio but you will have an overflow because the browser will not go back to calculate the width of the container again:

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.image-container {
  flex: 1;
  align-self: center;
  border:2px solid blue;
}

.img {
  height: 100%;
}

.another-flex-child {
  flex: none;
  background-color: red;
}

.spacer {
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img class="img" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/firefox-logo.svg" >
  </div>
  <div class="another-flex-child">
    Random content here
  </div>
</div>

<div class="spacer"></div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <div>Properly centered content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="another-flex-child">
    Random content here
  </div>
</div>
```

To avoid this give the image a width and make sure to add [`min-height:0` to the container to allow it to shrink](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/8620333)

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.image-container {
  flex: 1;
  align-self: center;
  border:2px solid blue;
  min-height:0;
}

.img {
  height: 100%;
}

.another-flex-child {
  flex: none;
  background-color: red;
}

.spacer {
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img class="img" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/firefox-logo.svg" width="250">
  </div>
  <div class="another-flex-child">
    Random content here
  </div>
</div>

<div class="spacer"></div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <div>Properly centered content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="another-flex-child">
    Random content here
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If you were initially using an image with intrinsic dimension you won't have this issue and you don't need to define a width. You will only need to add `min-height:0` to avoid the overflow:

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.image-container {
  flex: 1;
  align-self: center;
  border:2px solid blue;
  min-height:0;
}

.img {
  height: 100%;
}

.another-flex-child {
  flex: none;
  background-color: red;
}

.spacer {
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/400/400">
  </div>
  <div class="another-flex-child">
    Random content here
  </div>
</div>

<div class="spacer"></div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <div>Properly centered content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="another-flex-child">
    Random content here
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that the above doesn't work the same way in Firefox and you will need to add `text-aling:center` to make sure it works the same everywhere:

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.image-container {
  flex: 1;
  align-self: center;
  border:2px solid blue;
  text-align:center;
  min-height:0;
}

.img {
  height: 100%;
}

.another-flex-child {
  flex: none;
  background-color: red;
}

.spacer {
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/400/400">
  </div>
  <div class="another-flex-child">
    Random content here
  </div>
</div>

<div class="spacer"></div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <div>Properly centered content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="another-flex-child">
    Random content here
  </div>
</div>
```

You will notice that the difference is related to the width calculation of the container which a bit complex due to the use of `height:100%`

Things may get worse if the size of the image is very small:

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.image-container {
  flex: 1;
  align-self: center;
  border:2px solid blue;
  text-align:center;
  min-height:0;
}

.img {
  height: 100%;
}

.another-flex-child {
  flex: none;
  background-color: red;
}

.spacer {
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/50/50">
  </div>
  <div class="another-flex-child">
    Random content here
  </div>
</div>

<div class="spacer"></div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <div>Properly centered content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="another-flex-child">
    Random content here
  </div>
</div>
```

In Firefox `text-align:center` will do nothing and you may need a nested flexbox container

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.image-container {
  flex: 1;
  align-self: center;
  justify-content:center;
  border:2px solid blue;
  display:flex;
  min-height:0;
}

.img {
  height: 100%;
}

.another-flex-child {
  flex: none;
  background-color: red;
}

.spacer {
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/50/50">
  </div>
  <div class="another-flex-child">
    Random content here
  </div>
</div>

<div class="spacer"></div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <div>Properly centered content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="another-flex-child">
    Random content here
  </div>
</div>
```

The below is almost the same issue you were having with the initial SVG that can fixed with this same code but it won't remove the overflow:

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.image-container {
  flex: 1;
  align-self: center;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  border:2px solid blue;
}

.img {
  height: 100%;
}

.another-flex-child {
  flex: none;
  background-color: red;
}

.spacer {
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img class="img" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/firefox-logo.svg" >
  </div>
  <div class="another-flex-child">
    Random content here
  </div>
</div>

<div class="spacer"></div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <div>Properly centered content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="another-flex-child">
    Random content here
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Another intresting thing to note is that your initial code may work fine if you add `height:100%` to the container making the calculation of the nested height easier:

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.image-container {
  flex: 1;
  align-self: center;
  border:2px solid blue;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  height:100%;
}

.img {
  height: 100%;
  display:block;
}

.another-flex-child {
  flex: none;
  background-color: red;
}

.spacer {
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img class="img" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/firefox-logo.svg" >
  </div>
  <div class="another-flex-child">
    Random content here
  </div>
</div>

<div class="spacer"></div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <div>Properly centered content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="another-flex-child">
    Random content here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought that the issue might be related to svg dimensions, but I saw the same problem with a png...

Comment: @Tobi no, you want have issue with a PNG or an image with intrinsic width/height. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/f58c2zj1/

Comment: Hmm, you are right...Just wondering what I actually tried in my manic experiments while trying to get it to work ;)

Comment: But seems your answer is a very viable solution, although I haven't fully gotten it yet

Comment: @Tobi with no intrinsic dimension your element will have a default width equal to 0 . that's why the container is shrinking .. if you later add height:100% you only make the image grow and overflow but not the container because the browser doesn't go back to avoid a cycle in the calculation

Comment: Great answer!! Would give you more than one upvote if I could :)
I noticed the difference between Firefox and Chrome and was wondering if that was an nonconformity in firefox. I don't do frontend too often but I am really amazed what can be done since Flex arrived. That being said, I probably could have solved my issue with JS in 10 minutes, but the curiosity how it should be done always prevails ;)

Comment: @Tobi sometimes the calculation is a bit tricky and difficult to figure out ... I have updated again to add another solution at the end, still tricky to explain but will also fix your issue

Answer (score 3):

Because your `<div>` that contains the image (and has `align-self: center` on it) is by default a block-level element, and has a `width` of `100%` by default. As such, it is constrained in relation to the *parent*.

In order to have your image centered correctly, you'll want to add `display: contents` with:

```
container .image-container {
  display: inline;
}
```

This can be seen in the following:

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container .image-container {
  flex: 1;
  align-self: center;
  display: contents;
}

.container .image-container .img {
  height: 100%;
}

.another-flex-child {
  flex: none;
  background-color: red;
}

.spacer {
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img class="img" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/firefox-logo.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="another-flex-child">
    Random content here
  </div>
</div>

<div class="spacer"></div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <div>Properly centered content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="another-flex-child">
    Random content here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well also only adding "overflow: auto;" on image-container makes everything looks as expected

Comment: *is by default a block-level element, and has a width of 100% by default. As such, it is constrained in relation to the parent.* --> what you mean by this? that div is a flex item and doesn't have width:100% also your image isn't really centred by it's stretched to fill all the container (add some border to see this)

Comment: @TemaniAfif is in fact right about that - accepting his answer...

Answer (score -1):

Add the justify-content like below:

```
.image-container {
    flex: 1;
    align-self: center;
    justify-content:center;
}
```

it should works